# Calculating trajectory of Voyager 1 Python

Tags: trajectory, voyager, python

I want to calculate the trajectory of the voyager 1 probe using python and Kepler equation. I know there are already various program to calculate it but I need to do it on my own via these calculations. First of all I used the parameters given here https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/science/hyperbolic-orbital-elements/ . Then I used Kepler Equation and newton method to approximate the position of the probe in space. The code below only show the trajectory until Jupiter and later on I will add other pieces. What I'm struggling here is the inclination of the ecliptic plane. In fact, I use get body barycentric to retrive the position of the planets in a given time but it appears that the orbit of the planet is not on the x-y plane even if my calculations for the probe seems to be referred to that plane. So I was wondering I could I put planets orbits on the x-y plane, or similarly, rotating the plane of orbit of the probe so that it has the correct inclination referred to the ecliptic plane. Maybe there's a command in Python differente from get-body-barycentric? As you can see from the images in the x-y plane the calculations seems correct. Should I do the same calculation with the planets without using get body?
Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import newton
import scipy.constants
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.coordinates import solar_system_ephemeris, EarthLocation
from astropy.coordinates import get_body_barycentric, get_body
from astropy import units as u

# Costanti
G = sp.constants.G  # Costante gravitazionale (m^3 kg^-1 s^-2)
M_S = 1.989*1E+30  # Massa del Sole (kg)
AU = 1.496*1E+8  # Unità Astronomica (km)

# Terra
t_0 = Time('1977-09-05T12:56:00', format='isot', scale='tdb') # t partenza Terra 

# Terra-Giove (orbita ellittica fino Giove)
# Parametri iniziali (rispetto al sole)
t_1 = Time('1977-09-08T09:08:17', format='isot', scale='tdb') # t Terra 
a_1 = 745761000              # Semiasse maggiore (km)
e_1 = 0.797783               # Eccentricità
ϕ_1 = 1.032182*(np.pi/180)   # Inclinazione (rad)
Ω_1 = -17.565509*(np.pi/180) # Longitudine di nodo ascendente (rad)
ω_1 = -0.767558*(np.pi/180)  # Argomento del pericentro (rad)
M_1 = 0.304932*(np.pi/180)   # Anomalia media iniziale (rad)


# Giove (orbita attorno a giove)
# Parametri all'arrivo intorno a Giove (rispetto a Giove)
t_2 = Time('1979-03-05T12:05:26', format='isot', scale='tdb') # t arrivo Giove 
a_2 = -1092356               # Semiasse maggiore (km)
e_2 = 1.318976               # Eccentricità
ϕ_2 = 3.979134*(np.pi/180)   # inclinazione (rad)
M_2 = 0.*(np.pi/180)         # Anomalia media iniziale (rad)

# Giove-Saturno (orbita iperbolica fino a Saturno)
# Parametri alla partenza da Giove (rispetto al sole)
t_3 = Time('1979-04-24T07:33:03', format='isot', scale='tdb') # t partenza Giove 
a_3 = -593237000             # Semiasse maggiore (km)
e_3 =  2.302740              # Eccentricità
ϕ_3 = 2.481580*(np.pi/180)   # inclinazione (rad)
M_3 = 19.156329*(np.pi/180)  # Anomalia media iniziale (rad)

# Saturno (orbita attorno a Saturno)
# Parametri all'arrivo intorno a Saturno (rispetto a Saturno)
t_4 = Time('1980-11-12T18:46:30', format='isot', scale='tdb') # t arrivo Saturno 
a_4 = -166152                # Semiasse maggiore (km)
e_4 = 2.107561               # Eccentricità
ϕ_4 = 65.893904*(np.pi/180)  # inclinazione (rad)
M_4 = 0.*(np.pi/180)         # Anomalia media iniziale (rad)

# Post-Saturno (orbita iperbolica)
# Parametri alla partenza da Saturno (rispetto al sole)
t_5 = Time('1991-01-01T00:00:00', format='isot', scale='tdb') # t partenza Saturno (fuso orario +0)
a_5 = -480926000             # Semiasse maggiore (km)
e_5 = 3.724716               # Eccentricità
ϕ_5 = 35.762854*(np.pi/180)  # inclinazione (rad)
M_5 = 688.967795*(np.pi/180) # Anomalia media iniziale (rad)

# Oggi 
t_6 = Time('2024-01-01T00:00:00', format='isot', scale='tdb')

# Definizione dell'equazione da risolvere (f(E) = M + e*sin(E) - E)
def ellisse(E, M, e):
    return M+e*np.sin(E)-E

# Definizione dell'equazione da risolvere (f(H) = M - e*sinh(H) + H)
def iperbole(H, M, e):
    return M-e*np.sinh(H)+H

# Creo numpy array negli intervalli di tempo specificati
t1 = np.linspace(t_1, t_2)
t2 = np.linspace(t_2, t_3)
t3 = np.linspace(t_3, t_4)
t4 = np.linspace(t_4, t_5)
t5 = np.linspace(t_5, t_6)

# e li unisco in un unico array
t = np.concatenate((t1,t2,t3,t4,t5))

# Adesso costruisco l'orbita per ogni intervallo di tempo
sun = np.zeros((len(t1), 3))
jup = np.zeros((len(t1), 3))
ter = np.zeros((len(t1), 3))
sonda = np.zeros((len(t1), 3))

n=np.sqrt(G*M_S/(a_1*1E+3)**3)

for i in range(len(t1)):
    
    sun[i] = get_body_barycentric('sun', t1[i]).xyz.value
    jup[i] = get_body_barycentric('jupiter', t1[i]).xyz.value
    ter[i] = get_body_barycentric('earth', t1[i]).xyz.value
    
    δt = (t1[i] - t1[0]).sec
    M_sonda = M_1 + n * δt
    E_sonda = newton(ellisse, M_sonda, args=(M_sonda, e_1))

    θ_sonda = 2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(1 + e_1)*np.sin(E_sonda / 2), np.sqrt(1 - e_1) * np.cos(E_sonda / 2))
    
    r_sonda = a_1 * (1 - e_1 * np.cos(E_sonda))
    
    x_sonda = r_sonda*(np.cos(Ω_1)*np.cos(θ_sonda+ω_1) - np.sin(Ω_1)*np.sin(θ_sonda+ω_1)*np.cos(ϕ_1))/AU
    y_sonda = r_sonda*(np.sin(Ω_1)*np.cos(θ_sonda+ω_1) + np.cos(Ω_1)*np.sin(θ_sonda+ω_1)*np.cos(ϕ_1))/AU
    z_sonda = r_sonda*np.sin(ϕ_1)*np.sin(θ_sonda+ω_1)/AU


    sonda[i] = np.array([x_sonda, y_sonda, z_sonda])

# Creazione della figura e degli assi
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Inizializzazione della traiettoria dei pianeti
traiettoria_sun, = ax.plot([], [], color='orange', label='Sole')
traiettoria_ter, = ax.plot([], [], color='green', label='Terra')
traiettoria_jup, = ax.plot([], [], color='black', label='Giove')
traiettoria_sonda, = ax.plot([], [], color='blue', label='Sonda')

# Inizializzazione dei pianeti come pallini
pianeta_sun, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='orange', markersize=15)
pianeta_ter, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='green', markersize=7)
pianeta_jup, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='black', markersize=12)
pallina_sonda, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='blue', markersize=5)

# Funzione di inizializzazione
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-5, 5)
    ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
    ax.set_zlim([-5, 5])
    ax.set_xlabel('X (UA)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y (UA)')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z (UA)')
    ax.set_title('Orbita della Sonda')
    ax.legend()

    return traiettoria_sun, traiettoria_ter, traiettoria_jup, pianeta_sun, pianeta_ter, pianeta_jup, traiettoria_sonda, pallina_sonda

# Funzione di aggiornamento per ogni frame
def update(frame):
    #if frame < len(t1):
    sun[frame] = get_body_barycentric('sun', t[frame]).xyz.value
    jup[frame] = get_body_barycentric('jupiter', t[frame]).xyz.value
    ter[frame] = get_body_barycentric('earth', t[frame]).xyz.value

        # Aggiorna la traiettoria dei pianeti
    traiettoria_sun.set_data(sun[:frame, 0], sun[:frame, 1])
    traiettoria_sun.set_3d_properties(sun[:frame, 2])
        
    traiettoria_ter.set_data(ter[:frame, 0], ter[:frame, 1])
    traiettoria_ter.set_3d_properties(ter[:frame, 2])
        
    traiettoria_jup.set_data(jup[:frame, 0], jup[:frame, 1])
    traiettoria_jup.set_3d_properties(jup[:frame, 2])
        
    traiettoria_sonda.set_data(sonda[:frame, 0], sonda[:frame, 1])
    traiettoria_sonda.set_3d_properties(sonda[:frame, 2])


        # Aggiorna la posizione dei pianeti come pallini
    pianeta_sun.set_data(sun[frame, 0], sun[frame, 1])
    pianeta_sun.set_3d_properties(sun[frame, 2])
        
    pianeta_ter.set_data(ter[frame, 0], ter[frame, 1])
    pianeta_ter.set_3d_properties(ter[frame, 2])
        
    pianeta_jup.set_data(jup[frame, 0], jup[frame, 1])
    pianeta_jup.set_3d_properties(jup[frame, 2])
        
    pallina_sonda.set_data(sonda[frame, 0], sonda[frame, 1])
    pallina_sonda.set_3d_properties(sonda[frame, 2])


    return traiettoria_sun, traiettoria_ter, traiettoria_jup, pianeta_sun, pianeta_ter, pianeta_jup, traiettoria_sonda, pallina_sonda

# Creazione dell'animazione
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(t1), init_func=init, blit=True)

# Visualizzazione dell'animazione nel notebook
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```

[image: Difference in plane]

[image: Different perspective]

[image: x-y plane view]

Comment: The Sun centered elements use Earth's orbit for the xy plane, so Jupiter will generally not be on that plane.  You mentioned struggling with "the inclination of the ecliptic plane", but the important thing to know is the ecliptic plane has no inclination.  Rather, it is Jupiter's orbit which is inclined relative to the ecliptic plane.

Comment: Jupiter's inclination is quite low, but the Voyager 1 trajectory is deflected slightly north of the ecliptic at the Jupiter encounter, which enables it to meet Saturn. And then Saturn deflects it substantially north. So you really need to work in 3D to do this properly. https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=%27Voyager%201%27

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Still, the best way to do it for me was to manually calculate the approximate positions of the planet via NASA formulae. This way I could use the same method I used for the orbit of Voyager 1 and everything went good.